# Convergence of recursive sequence similar to harmonic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Given $k>1$ and sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies $0<a_1<1$, and $\forall n\ge1$:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_n^k}{n^k} $$
Prove: $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

I think there is a limit to $\{a_n\}$, but I cannot find a function to fit it and use induction, such as:

$$a_n<C(1-n^{1-k})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's prove by induction that $a_n \leq na_1$ for every $n \geq 1$. The inequality is clearly true for $n=1$, and if it holds for an integer $n \geq 1$, then
$$a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{a_n^k}{n^k} \leq na_1 + \dfrac{(na_1)^k}{n^k} = na_1 + a_1^k < (n+1)a_1$$

since $0 <a_1 < 1$. This closes the induction.

Now, for every $n \geq 1$, one has
$$\dfrac{1}{a_n} - \dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}} =\dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_na_{n+1}} = \dfrac{ a_n^{k-1}}{n^ka_{n+1}}$$

Using $a_{n+1} > a_n$ and the proven fact that $a_n < na_1$, one deduces that
$$\dfrac{1}{a_n} - \dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}} < \dfrac{a_n^{k-2}}{n^k} \leq \dfrac{(na_1)^{k-2}}{n^k} =\dfrac{a_1^{k-2}}{n^2} < \dfrac{1}{n^2} ,\quad \quad   \text{so}  \quad \quad \dfrac{1}{a_n} - \dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}} < \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)} \quad (*)$$

For every integer $2 \leq m < N $, if we sum the inequalities $(*)$ from $n=m$ to $N-1$, we get
$$\sum_{n=m}^{N-1}\dfrac{1}{a_n} - \dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}} < \sum_{n=m}^{N-1}\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}  = \sum_{n=m}^{N-1}\dfrac{1}{n-1}- \dfrac{1}{n} $$

and both sides telescope to give
$$\dfrac{1}{a_m} - \dfrac{1}{a_{N}} < \dfrac{1}{m-1}- \dfrac{1}{N} < \dfrac{1}{m-1}, \quad\quad\quad \text{i.e.} \quad\quad\quad \dfrac{1}{a_N} >  \dfrac{1}{a_m} -\dfrac{1}{m-1}\quad (**) $$

In particular, let's define an integer $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m >\dfrac{1}{1-a_1}$.

One has $ma_1 < m-1$, so $a_m < m-1$. If we put $C = \dfrac{1}{a_m} -\dfrac{1}{m-1}$, we have $C > 0$.

The inequality $(**)$ then gives that for every $N >m$,
$$\dfrac{1}{a_N} \geq C > 0$$

In particular, $(a_n)$ cannot tend to $+\infty$, and since it is increasing, it converges.

Comment: Nice answer ! (+)